# PHP - storing variable values upon a link click, and keeping the value the same as user navigates

Tags: php, variables, url, session-variables

I have a situation where URL's need to carry variable values to another page.

Sometimes the URL will only need to carry one variable value, like here:

```
<a href="test2.php?occupation=<?php echo $Occupation; ?>">Anchor Text</a>
```

Or it may need to carry multiple variable values, like here.

```
<a href="test2.php?occupation=<?php echo $Occupation; ?>&firstName=<?php echo $FirstName; ?>&lastName=<?php echo $LastName; ?>">Anchor Text</a>
```

The amount of variable values the URL carrys depends on how many variables receive a value from the GET statements on the page. If the GET statements are empty, then there is no need to carry the value to the next page in the link.

```
$FirstName = $_GET["firstName"];
$LastName = $_GET["lastName"];
$Occupation = $_GET["occupation"];
```

I want to avoid putting more variables in the URL than are needed. But to make sure all variables get carried, I would have to use the second link above which contains all the possible variables (in case all variables are NOT empty).

So here's my question: is there a way to store a value into a variable upon the click of a link, and then keep the same value in the variable as the user navigates through pages, without having to put that variable value in every link the user clicks on? I know SESSIONS will work, but disabling cookies will cause some issues. I want to be safe from any client side issues.

Comment: http_build_query(); ?

Comment: safe from client side issues? you are aware that parameters in the URL can be directly edited? As can the html source that the browser is showing? What client side issues are you concerned about? All you need to do is validate the input data very carefully. If you are really concerned then use HTTPS (SSL).

Comment: The client side issue I'm concerned about is if the user disables cookies.

Answer (score 0):

[http_build_query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)

(PHP 5)

http_build_query — Generate URL-encoded query string

```
<?php
$data = array('foo'=>'bar',
              'baz'=>'boom',
              'cow'=>'milk',
              'php'=>'hypertext processor');

echo http_build_query($data) . "\n";
echo http_build_query($data, '', '&amp;');

?>
```

The above example will output:

```
foo=bar&baz=boom&cow=milk&php=hypertext+processor
foo=bar&amp;baz=boom&amp;cow=milk&amp;php=hypertext+processor
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm not familiar the http_buid_query, but I will research. Thanks for directing me in the right direction.

Comment: put my answer up if it helped

Answer (score 0):

```
ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', true);
ini_set('session.use_cookies', false);
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', false);
```

and the session is not stored in any cookie(s)!

Comment: Thanks! I'm not familiar the code above, but I will research. Thanks for directing me in the right direction.